# shared_pointer of a base class cannot be created using a polymorphic derived

Tags: c++, casting, shared-ptr

I have a base polymorphic class ( with virtual methods ) and a derived from it.
I am trying to use the following code

```
     boost::shared_ptr<base_class> ptr( new derived_class() );
```

but the compiler returns me the following error

```
    cannot convert ‘fpga_northwest*’ to ‘fpga*’ in initialization
    make: *** [../obj/ixecute_cmd_interface.o] Error 1
```

Reading a look around I am tempted to use the following that builds ok, but I have some doubts. Do you think that it is correct?

```
     boost::shared_ptr<base_class> ptr_base;
     boost::shared_ptr<derived_class> ptr_derived( new derived_class() );
     ptr_base = boost::dynamic_pointer_cast<base_class>( ptr_derived );
```

If I use a `boost::static_pointer_cast` I have compiler error; since I am casting from a derived to a base should not be more correct a `static_cast`?

Thanks for your help

Comment: try `dynamic_cast<base_class>(deriver_class object)`

Comment: don't get it, this appears to work fine: http://www.ideone.com/N63Qf

Comment: Hm, [this example](http://ideone.com/3Lzys) works fine. How is your code different?

Comment: @Nim: Your example fails to compile when you use private inheritance. Maybe that is what the OP did wrong?

Comment: @Bjorn, that will report a different error AFAIK (something like inaccessible base... blah-de-blah). I don't think any cast will help there either..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
boost::shared_ptr<base_class> ptr( new derived_class() );
```

This should work just fine.

Perhaps those classes are not related after all?

Perhaps those classes are incomplete at that point, so the compiler doesn't know that the classes are related? (This should produce other error as well, though.)

Comment: I would vote for incomplete definitions of the classes at the point of use... +1

Comment: Hi I need to check that 'cos derived_class inherits base_class but it doesn't work.

Comment: ..when this could happen? I cannot understand becasue I built a sample elsewhere and now it builds!?!?!

Comment: ...I checked and you are right...I had a typo in my code!! :(

Answer (score 3):

This should work as stated originally. A derived_class* will happily cast down to a base_class* with which to construct the shared_ptr. As pointed out, ideone will compile it too. I suggest there is something wrong with your Boost installation or compiler.

Or, as pointed out, the rest of your code.

Comment: Actually shared_ptr should happily accept a derived class pointer as a parameter and then do the upcasting.

Answer (score 1):

Type coercion is needed to be able to do this cast, which is implemented via a member template. This is not too well supported on older Compilers. Therefore it is disabled on these compilers. What compiler are you using?